# I am trying to connect AWS IoT to my Arduino UNO, but there is some connection issue i am facing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I am using this command

```
C:\Users\*******\aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2\samples>py pubsub.py --topic topic_1 --ca_file "C:\Users\HP*************\AmazonRootCA1.pem" --cert "C:\Users\***********certificate.pem.crt" --key "C:\Users*************private.pem.key" --endpoint ********p-south-1.amazonaws.com
Connecting to ********ap-south-1.amazonaws.com with client ID 'test-2b05cc3d-70e6-4a15-8798-6057fbffaa13'...
Connected!
Subscribing to topic 'topic_1'...
Connection interrupted. error: AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
Connection resumed. return_code: 0 session_present: True
Connection interrupted. error: AWS_ERROR_MQTT_UNEXPECTED_HANGUP: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

while connecting it will again and again trying to connect and executing infinitly.
what do do for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with my raspberry pi.  Turns out the problem had to do with the policies not allowing the topics.  I was successfully able to pubsub using the test topic sdk/test/python  but any other topic would fail.

I eventually came to this page and it answered my problem by showing me where to look: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/attach-to-cert.html)

Once I modified the policy attached to my "thing" I was able to publish any topic I desired.

Here is where you can manage your policies inside of
[AWS IoT Core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSrtr.png)  Under Manage -> Security -> Policies

I hope that helps.  If you need help modifying the policy let me know I'll show you what I did to mine.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for contributing by answering questions! Regarding what you said: *If you need help modifying the policy let me know I'll show you what I did to mine*. Please don't keep the information only to you and the asker: just edit your answer and add that to your answer so everyone can enjoy the information!

Comment: @Koedlt  Are you needing that information?  I'm very happy to add it to my response I just didn't want to make a long post if simply pointing someone to the right place allowed them to solve the problem.  Thank you for the feed back though I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not in need of that information, just trying to make this website as high quailty as possible :) Indeed, a very long answer is not necessarily what we need but if you can put the core information in there (the information that will help the future readers solve this issue on their own) that would be awesome!